# Prove that always picking the smallest two elements to add gives the smallest cost?

Tags: algorithms

> There are $N$ numbers in a set originally. You can pick two numbers $A, B$ from the set and add them together in an operation with a cost of $A + B$. Then the two numbers are removed from the set and $A + B$ is inserted into the set. Find the strategy to minimize the total cost such that only $1$ number remains in the set.

Picking the smallest two elements to add every time should be the optimal strategy here. However, I didn't know how to prove that this is the optimal way. I thought about proving by contradiction but didn't see where to begin with. Could someone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Addition is commutative so it doesn’t matter?

Comment: @spino The cost is not the sum of numbers.

Comment: Is it any binary operation? You state ”add” numbers together.

Comment: @spinosarus123 It should be the **total** cost instead of the last cost. So for example the set contains $1, 2, 3$. You first add $1 + 2$ with a cost of $3$. Then add $3$ and $3$ with a cost of $6$. The total cost will be $9$.